# sending base64 string using HttpWebRequest in c# convert "+" to white space issue

Tags: c#

i convert an image to base64 string to upload through HttpWebRequest in c#.on server side when i receive base64 string the "+" signs have been converted to white spaces" ". it give me error to convert this base64 string to byte array.i do not want to make any change on server side(in web services). i want to resolve this issues on client side.my client side code is as follow.

//////////////////

WSManagerResult wsResult = new WSManagerResult();

```
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(serviceURL);
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            //  req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
            // req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();


            string content = string.Empty;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in paramDic)
            {
```

// entry.Value is  a base 64 string gene rated from image

```
             content = content + entry.Key + "=" + entry.Value + "&&";
            }
            content = content.TrimEnd('&'); // input parameter if u have more that one //a=b&dd=aa               
            req.ContentLength = content.Length;
            // req = URLEncode(content);
            Stream wri = req.GetRequestStream();


            byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);
            if (array.Length > 0)
                wri.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
            wri.Flush();
            wri.Close();
            WebResponse rsp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();


            byte[] b = null;
            using (Stream stream = rsp.GetResponseStream())
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int count = 0;
                do
                {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    count = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
                    ms.Write(buf, 0, count);
                } while (stream.CanRead && count > 0);
                b = ms.ToArray();
            }
            wsResult.result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            clsException.ExceptionInstance.HandleException(e);
            wsResult.error = e.Message;
        }


        return wsResult;
```

All the "+" signs in above base64 string are converted in to " " white spaces.which causes the issue as describe above.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Regards

shah Khalid

Comment: I always try to minimize my question(code/input) before asking...Now I realize it's very important and good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists an encoding called [Base64Url encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#RFC_4648) that's designed for just that.  However you may have to do the encoding / decoding on their respective ends.

In Base64 Url, it converts `+` to `-` and `/` to `_` so that it can be safely passed over the wire without the standard URL encoders adding weirdness like spaces, or percent-hex

Comment: many thanks Rob.it resolved my issue by replacing '+' to it hexadecimal '%2B' on the client side to post data through wire.as below in c#. /*Using standard Base64 in URL requires encoding of '+', '/' and '=' characters into
                special percent-encoded hexadecimal sequences ('+' = '%2B', '/' = '%2F' and '=' = '%3D')*/ String   stbase64datatopost =stbase64datatopost.Replace("+",@"%2B"); stbase64datatopost  = stbase64datatopost .Replace("/",@"%2F");
               stbase64datatopost=stbase64datatopost.Replace("=",@"%3D");

Answer (score 4):

many thanks Rob.it resolved my issue by replacing '+' to it hexadecimal '%2B' on the client side to post data through wire.as below in c#.

```
/*Using standard Base64 in URL requires encoding of '+', '/' and '=' characters into special percent-encoded hexadecimal sequences ('+' = '%2B', '/' = '%2F' and '=' = '%3D')*/ 

String stbase64datatopost =stbase64datatopost.Replace("+",@"%2B"); 
stbase64datatopost = stbase64datatopost .Replace("/",@"%2F");      
stbase64datatopost=stbase64datatopost.Replace("=",@"%3D");
```

Comment: This worked for me. In my case the + was getting replaced with a space and the / or = with a carriage return.

Answer (score 1):

Try posting your base64 encoded data to web service with `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(entry)`

Web service should able to parse it without changing the code